# htaccess hide partial of query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

here is my issue.

i want to rewrite it

from

> www.domain.com/?cur=artist/profile&id=1&title=username -actual url that apache read

to

> www.domain.com/username -after rewrite and appear on browser link

the idea is similar to facebook

> https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=123456789012345 -before set username on account setting
>
> https://www.facebook.com/username -after set username

but in my case, i have my username on the query string. therefore, i just need to remove `?cur=artist/profile&id=1&title=` from query string n left `username` only.

Comment: Rewrite *to* or rewrite *from*?

Comment: Please give some real life samples: what the user should write in his/her browser, and how the URL should be internally transformed in the server.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that using a `RewriteRule` directly, you need to use a `RewriteCond`. Well, two, here: one for the request, the other for the query string.

The following example will work, provided that `var_a` is at the beginning -- if it isn't, the regex will be more complicated. If you need a more complete answer, please complete your question:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$  # match "/index.php"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)=1&var_b=2 # capture "var_a" in the query string
RewriteRule .* /var_b?%1=1 [QSA] # rewrite to /var_b?var_a=1
```

Comment: yes, the var_a is always in the first order... how about i give my current real example.

i want to rewrite it from

> www.domain.com/?cur=artist/profile&id=1&title=name

to

> www.domain.com/name

 .by the way, thanks for your answer, fge... however i still not understand the condition above...

Comment: And you don't care about other query string parameters? Can you edit your question with the full, real-world example?